# lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

It is showing lateinit property recyclerView has not been initialized. Please help to out to figure out the problem.

```
class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity(), NewsItemClicked {

    private lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NewsListAdapter


    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        fetchData()
        mAdapter = NewsListAdapter(this)
        recyclerView.adapter = mAdapter

    }
```

I m confused too much

Comment: you have not initialized recyclerview. Are you using koltin android extension?

Comment: You'll need to do `recyclerview = findViewById('id of recyclerview')` after `setContentView ` in `onCreate`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize all the lateinit vars before calling on them!